# When you modify a jQuery collection within an each loop, is the modified collection included or just the original?

Tags: jquery, clone, each, insertafter

When you modify a jQuery collection within an each loop, is the modified collection included or just the original?

For example

```
var collection = $("div");
$(collection).each(function(){
    var originalDiv = $(this);
    var cloneDiv = $(this).clone();
    cloneDiv.insertAfter(originalDiv);
});
```

Are the clone divs now included in the loop or is it only the original collection?

Comment: There's no reason for the `$()` in `$(collection)` above. `collection` is *already* a jQuery object.

Comment: Yeah, you can even do `$("div").each(function() {`

Comment: *"When you modify a jQuery collection within an each loop"* - you're not modifying the *collection*

Comment: Its literally just some sample code I quickly wrote to go with the question but thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery object in `collection` is unaffected by the `clone` and `insertAfter` calls you're doing in the loop. jQuery objects are snapshots (like the ones you get from `querySelectorAll`), not live collections (like the ones you get from `getElementsByTagName` or `getElementsByClassName` or similar), and neither `clone` nor `insertAfter` adds it to `collection`.

You can easily prove this to yourself:

```js
// Your code (without the unnecessary `$()` around `collection`
var collection = $("div");
collection.each(function(){
    var originalDiv = $(this);
    var cloneDiv = $(this).clone();
    cloneDiv.insertAfter(originalDiv);
});

// Now, do another operation on the contents of `collection` -- notice how only
// the original contents are affected, not the divs created during the loop
collection.css("color", "blue");
```

```html
<div>a</div>
<div>b</div>
<div>c</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Even if you were using one of the methods to add the element to a jQuery object, in general, jQuery methods create new jQuery objects rather than modifying the state of the jQuery object you call them on. (I think there are exceptions to that rule, but one doesn't immediately come to mind.) For instance, you can "add" an element by calling `add`, but it doesn't change the jQuery object you call it on; instead, it creates and returns a *new* jQuery object containing the original elements and the new one.